# how to justify text in UITextView in iphone?

Tags: iphone, justify

how to justify text in `UITextView`
I try this like this but this code do not give any output.

```
[web loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:
     @"<html><body><p align=\"justify\"> %@ </p> </body></html>",
     [dict1 objectForKey:@"services_description"]] baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: I like how descriptive and concise this title is.

Comment: hope now u are satisfied with the question?

Comment: Now that someone edited it to include correct formatting, yes. I still don't know though how all this is related to UITextView. This is about an UIWebView, right?

Comment: Do you want  to display text on UITextView , just give textViewname.text=@"text"; or assidn text file.

Answer (score 2):

```
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
```

This only works on iOS 6 and above

Comment: plus 1 for actually answering the question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest You to use WebView Because justified aligment for text you only have center, left and right by `UITextView`.

IF You Want to Use `UIWebView` then set in

```
className.h

@interface className : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webviewName;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webviewName;
```

className.m

```
[webviewName loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div align='justify'>%@<div>",TEXT_set] baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: i try this code but this is not work....so plz give other code for this problem...

Comment: where are you using it...webView or TextView

Answer (score 0):

You can justify the text in the UITextView by choosing the alignment from the utilities

Comment: But i don't use alignment property of uitextview, i have lot of text in uitextview but every line have diffrent-diffrent amount of text , so i want aligne all text equily....

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a HTML Page with propertext allignment  and then Load the Local HTML page in a Webview.

```
  webView = [UIWebView alloc] init];

[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```